# jQuery ajax not working on ActionLink

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

Ajax is not working, I have tested by adding input button and it works for that but it does not work for ActionLink. I have added jQuery bundle on my cshtml. I am using latest jQuery version 2.0.

This is my code:

View:

```
<span> @Ajax.ActionLink(
"Name Ajax",
"ShowUser",
new
{
 id = 1,
 sort = "FullName"
},
new AjaxOptions
{
 HttpMethod = "POST",
 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
 UpdateTargetId = "userGridDiv",
 OnBegin = "myonbegin",
 OnSuccess = "myonsuccess",
 OnComplete = "myoncomplete",
 OnFailure = "myonfailure"
},
new 
{
  @class = "grid-link",
}
)
/span>

@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#animatedgif").hide();
});

  function myonbegin() {
        //show animated gif
        alert("helloworld");
        $("#animatedgif").show();
    }
    function myonsuccess() {
        //disable animated gif
        $("#animatedgif").hide();
    }
    function myonfailure() {
        //disbale animated gif
        $("#animatedgif").hide();
    }
    function myoncomplete() {
        //disable animated gif
        $("#animatedgif").hide();
    }
</script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ViewResult ShowUser(int id, string sort)
{
    User obj = new User();
    var model = obj.GetUsers(id, sort);
    View("userView", model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the requests that are being sent from the google chrome developer tool. In the `Network` page when clicking on the actionlink. That has to provide you the clue.

The code that you have given above is working fine for me. Also please check if there are any javascript errors in Chrome Developer tool. You will get red colored numbers on the extreme bottom right corner of the developer tool.

Click on the numbers to see the details of the error. Or else post the errors for us to analyze and guide you.